# Hide Top Bar in Gnome (Workspaces)

Tags: gnome, workspaces, menu

Is there any way to eliminate the top bar for all workspaces which are not the first/main one?

I mean, a tweak or files to edit so only the main workspace shows a top bar on top.

Comment: This extension below might help: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's a wonderful extension, but unfortunately it flickers in combination with fullscreen non-GTK apps. Hiding the top bar in workspaces is a kind of workaround. Here more info I've got on how to do it: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/hide-top-bar-in-workspaces/12182/5